# Is it really possible to make all possible numbers with an infinite binary table?

Tags: binary

Suppose I have an imaginary computer, with an infinite binary table, like the one below:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cdots & 128s & 64s & 32s & 16s & 8s & 4s & 2s & 1s
\end{array}
$$

If you don't already know how to make integers with a binary table, this is how it's done. To make an integer place a $1$ under the desired columns of the table, then add the values of each column where there is a $1$ together, and you get your number. Here's an example:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
128s & 64s & 32s & 16s & 8s & 4s & 2s & 1s & \text{result}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6
\end{array}
$$

My question is, how is it possible to make every [positive] [real] [whole] number with our imaginary infinite binary table? Will there be numbers that can't be made?

Comment: Irrational numbers!

Comment: Any (positive) integer can be represented like this, in a unique way, but for large integers you might need many places. By the way, if you strip the table and just keep the zeros and ones (like $110$ in your example), you've successfully written down your number in base $2$, or binary.

Comment: @YiyuanLee Edited question.

Comment: @Arthur I have the table for clarity. Also, edited my question.

Comment: With your table, you'd still have trouble with $\frac{1}{3}$ or $\pi$, just as you would have with normal base ten, but as I said, any whole, positive number works completely fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to represent non integer numbers, you must expand your table to the right, adding $1/2$, $1/4$, $1/8$ and so on. Just like decimal representation. For the sign, you must add an additional slot. Usually $0$ means positive and $1$ negative.